# Do I need multiple font faces if I upload a custom font face?

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of uploaded fonts in my website's folder. I understand that you need a backup font if the usual font is not available, but if I am uploading the font, do I still need this? I would think not, but let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, adding a CSS font stack is the best practice. It's easy to do and can only make things better and more reliable, and there are no downsides. For example, say that a site is being loaded on a very slow connection on an outdated smartphone, the font might not load at all or the text could load before the font. A font stack can provide a reasonable alternative or smooth the jump from the system font to the loaded one, Century Gothic to Avenir rather than Times New Roman to Avenir.